# Make Facebook share button works in iframe and share parent page URL with iframe meta tags

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-opengraph, facebook-social-plugins

I am working on the embeddable quiz widget. Let's say we have page with quiz iFrame `http://page.com/quiz`, iframe src is `http://quizes.com/quizes/1`. I use this JS code to init Facebook share button:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'http://quizes.com/quizes/1?result_id=2'
});
```

At `http://quizes.com/quizes/1?result_id=2` we render `og:title`, `og:description` and `og:image` based on user result. The thing is that if quiz is embedded in Facebook post I want to see parent domain (`page.com`) but it is `quizes.com` (gistroll.com– real project domain).

[image]

I tried to pass parent page url to share link like this: `http://quizes.com/quizes/1?result_id=2&url=http://page.com/quiz` and use `url` in `og:url`, but Facebook Crawler follows `http://page.com/quiz` in this case and of course there are wrong og meta tags there.

**Question**: Any ideas how fix that and show different domain in Facebook feed? (May be we can pass all necessary params with JS?)